Best way to add inbetween delay in HTTP requests from a single IP?
I need to delay HTTP requests sent from a specific IP by 1sec each.
By delay I mean it must be inserted between request, not just postpone it.
Just to be clear if I get 2 request at the same second at 01:00:00, it should process them in a FIFO queue, the first at 01:00:00 (or 01:00:01) and the second at 01:00:01 (or 01:00:02). I don't want both requests being processed together at 01:00:01.
I need to have a delay between request because the request itself is CPU consuming and I don't want to have multiple requests overlapping. Changing the request send timing from source is not an option, as they don't care.
I'm using Litespeed Enterprise as webserver.
Also I can't use a simple rate limiter, because it's not about bandwidth use, I need a per request/sec limit.
After googling a bit the solutions I found are:

Using iptables + tc with netem

iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -s <source_ip> -j MARK --set-mark 1
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: netem delay 100ms


Using mod_security, but it doesn't seem to support keeping a queue?
Others (ie. using NFQUEUE with an userland sw, etc)

My questions:

Does the tc solution adds in between packets delay or just postpone them?
I'd prefer something at layer7 level to match a single HTTP request, rather than packets. Is it possible to manage a queue with mod_sec (or other LS aware module) and how? Even a PHP module could be a solution.
Any suggestion in general? Other alternatives?

